# How to override/provide custom instances using bs-deriving

Tags: reason, bucklescript, deriving

Using bs-deriving, I can derive e.g. `show` instances using `[@deriving show]`. However, it's not clear how I would use the same derivation but providing a custom show instance for a specific datatype.

Example:

```ml
[@deriving show]
type bar = |Bar(int);

[@deriving show]
type foo = |Foo(int, bar);
```

Using the above example, how would I change Bar to print its integer in e.g. hexadecimal?

Comment: I think that's a bit too advanced for the simple BuckleScript implementation, although you could try using `@printer` like in [ppx_deriving](https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving#plugin-show).

Comment: What do you mean about "the simple bucklescript implementation"? Is there something else I could be using?

Comment: Oh sorry, BuckleScript comes with [its own simplified deriving mechanism](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/generate-converters-accessors), but that's not what you're talking about. `bs-deriving` seem to be a port of ppx_deriving, so `@printer` should work there too. I'll write an answer...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `@printer` to define your own printer function like this:

```ml
[@deriving show]
type bar = Bar([@printer fmt => fprintf(fmt, "0x%x")] int);
```

`fprintf` is a locally defined function which takes a [formatter](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html), a [format string](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html) and a number of values as specified by the format string. For brevity in this case we partially apply it to avoid having to explicitly pass the `int` value. It's equivalent to `(fmt, n) => fprintf(fmt, "0x%x", n)`.

The format string specifies that the number should be formatted as hexadecimal with lowercase letters (the `%x` part) and prefixed with `0x`. So `31` would output `0x1f`.